# Spectre - measuring subcircuit current with wild cards

Tags: circuit-design, spice, cadence

Presently I am measuring sub circuit current as under:

```
.probe isub(segio.Vdd)
```

Its working well but i have to write separately for all subcircuit.

Is there any option to use wild card or give depth in spectre as under:

```
.probe isub(segio. *.Vdd) depth=10
```

Comment: With wildcards: no, that is not possible. You could use a SKILL script to traverse through the hierarchy of the design though. But this is not so easy to code especially if you have no experience with SKILL. You could try to find an example on the Cadence support forum.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't use wild card or can't give depth value to use the

```
.probe isub()
```

multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what I am missing here, but my Spectre version is able to do this. From the Spectre help:

```
Output parameters
9       save=selected     Signals to output  public. Possible values are all, lvl, allpub, lvlpub, selected, none, and
                          nooutput.
10      autosavecurvolt=no
                          Automatically save terminal currents and node voltage. Possible values are no and yes.
11      nestlvl=infinity  Levels of subcircuits to output.
12      subcktprobelvl=0  Level up to which the subcircuit terminal currents are to be computed.
13      subcktiprobes=yes
                          Insert iprobes when computing subcircuit terminal currents. Possible values are no and yes.
14      amsiprobes=no     Insert iprobes when computing MDL-related terminal currents. Possible values are no and yes.
15      termcur_method=default
                          Select methods to compute terminal currents. Set termcur_method=complete to get correct currents
                          when devices have no termcurs output. However, this may negatively impact performance.. Possible
                          values are default and complete.
16      currents=selected
                          Terminal currents to output. (See important note in the description below the parameter
                          descriptions about saving currents by using probes). Possible values are all, nonlinear, selected,
                          and none.
17      useprobes=no      Use current probes when measuring terminal currents. (See important note in the description below
                          the parameter descriptions about saving currents by using probes). Possible values are no and
                          yes.
```

I use subcktprobelvl all the time, so it definitely works.

I don't use wildcards very often but the documentation says:

```
save x*.*1 sigtype=subckt
Saves all terminal currents of subcircuits from level 2 and above whose name starts with `x' and ends in `1'. For example,
x1.x21:2, x1.x2.x31:3
```

Currently I'm on Spectre Version 14.

Comment: I tried using save and *lvl commands but couldnt get correct syntax. I implimented it as under but surely there should be a better way to do the same.

Comment: Maybe you have to switch to spectre syntax mode using "simulator lang=spectre" for this to work.

Comment: Save segio:VDD probelvl=10

Answer (score 0):

probe isub(SEGIOX2.VDD)
.probe isub(SEGIOX2.SEGIO0.VDD)
.probe isub(SEGIOX2.REBUF.VDD)
.probe isub(SEGIOX2.SEGIO0.G_IO.VDD)
.probe isub(SEGIOX2.SEGIO0.G_IO.IO_COM.VDD)
.probe isub(SEGIOX2.SEGIO0.G_IO.IO_COM.IO_COM_F_0.VDD)
.probe isub(SEGIOX2.SEGIO0.G_IO.IO_COM.IO_COM_F_0.WRITE0.VDD)

.probe isub(SEGARRAYX2.SEG0.BANK_MAX.HBANK.LBL.LBLX4_0.VDD)
.probe isub(SEGARRAYX2.SEG0.BANK_MAX.HBANK.LBL.LBLX4_1.VDD)
.probe isub(SEGARRAYX2.SEG0.BANK_MAX.HBANK.LBL.LBLX4_2.VDD)
.probe isub(SEGARRAYX2.SEG0.BANK_MAX.HBANK.LBL.LBLX4_3.VDD)
.probe isub(SEGARRAYX2.SEG0.BANK_MAX.HBANK.LBL.LBLX4_4.VDD)
.probe isub(SEGARRAYX2.SEG0.BANK_MAX.HBANK.LBL.LBLX4_5.VDD)
.probe isub(SEGARRAYX2.SEG0.BANK_MAX.HBANK.LBL.LBLX4_6.VDD)
.probe isub(SEGARRAYX2.SEG0.BANK_MAX.HBANK.LBL.LBLX4_7.VDD)
.probe isub(SEGARRAYX2.SEG0.BANK_MAX.HBANK.LBL.LBLX4_8.VDD)